# Raspberry Pi Bash Script for network adapter, ip addresss and Mac address

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

I want to have a short cut to display the adapter, IP address and Mac address. I have the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
for iface in $(ifconfig | grep -v "lo" | cut -d ' ' -f1| tr '\n' ' ')
do 
   ipadd=$(ip -o -4 addr list $iface | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)
   madd=$(ip -o link list $iface | awk '{print $17}')
   printf "$iface\t$ipadd\t$madd\n"
done
```

1. The ethernet adapter doesn't show IP address and show as no such device. But if I run the command manually in bash it work and show up. ***The same script work correctly on my Ubuntu but not on Raspberry Pi*** (only manual command work). wlan0 works with no problem on Pi
2. The MAC address doesn't work at all, but if I run the command manually `ip -o link list <adapter> | awk '{print $17}')` it show the Mac address correctly.

Please advise where could have gone wrong.

Update:

```
+++ ifconfig
+++ grep -v lo
+++ cut -d ' ' -f1
+++ tr '\n' ' '
++ for iface in $(ifconfig | grep -v "lo" | cut -d ' ' -f1| tr '\n' ' ')
+++ ip -o -4 addr list enxb827ebe7229c:
+++ awk '{print $4}'
+++ cut -d/ -f1
Device "enxb827ebe7229c:" does not exist.
++ ipadd=
+++ ip -o -4 link list enxb827ebe7229c:
+++ awk '{print $17}'
Device "enxb827ebe7229c:" does not exist.
++ madd=
++ printf 'enxb827ebe7229c:\t\t\n'
enxb827ebe7229c:        
++ for iface in $(ifconfig | grep -v "lo" | cut -d ' ' -f1| tr '\n' ' ')
+++ ip -o -4 addr list wlan0:
+++ awk '{print $4}'
+++ cut -d/ -f1
++ ipadd=192.168.1.4
+++ ip -o -4 link list wlan0:
+++ awk '{print $17}'
RTNETLINK answers: No such device
Cannot send link get request: No such device
++ madd=
++ printf 'wlan0:\t192.168.1.4\t\n'
wlan0:  192.168.1.4
```

If I run the command manually:

```
ip -o -4 link list enxb827ebe7229c | awk '{print $17}'
```

I get the Mac address

If I run this

```
ip -o addr list enxb827ebe7229c | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1
```

I too will get the ipaddress correctly

Comment: Add `set -x` to the beginning of the script, run it on raspberry pi and post the output here. [How to debug a bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script). The script, although little strange, looks ok. `but not on` - how do you detect the "not work correctly" state on raspberry pi? How does it not work? Does it print anything? Does it fail with an error message? Does it exit with nonzero exit status?

Comment: Your `ifconfig | grep -v "lo:" | cut -d ' ' -f1| tr '\n' ' '` leaves the `:` in the buffer, so you are iterating over `eth0: eth1:`. Most probably you need to remove the `:`. Probably the `ifconfig` differes between platforms, and one prints the `:` and the other not

Comment: @KamilCuk I have updated my post with the output.

Comment: Just what I suspected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small fix was enough:

```
for iface in $(ifconfig | grep -v "lo:" | cut -d ' ' -f1 | cut -d: -f1); do
     ipadd=$(ip -o -4 addr list $iface | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1);
     madd=$(ip -o link list $iface | awk '{print $17}');
     printf "$iface\t$ipadd\t$madd\n";
done
```

The part `ifconfig | grep -v "lo:" | cut -d ' ' -f1| tr '\n' ' '` leaves the `:` character in the output, so you are iterating over `eth0: eth1:` not over `eth0 eth1`. You need to remove the `:`, either with a simple `cut -d: -f1` or `tr -d:` or any other mean.

Also note, as you've just discovered, the `ifconfig` output differs between platforms and implementations. It's better to just stick to the new `ip` command. Ex. `ip a | sed -n '/^[^ ]*: \([^ ]*\):.*/{s//\1/;p;}'`

There is no need for `tr '\n' ' '`. Shell interprets any whitespace character - that is tab, space or newline - as a word separator.

Comment: Its working... thanks, spend me almost 3 hours trying to find a solution! noted on the cut part, hopefully wouldn't make the same mistake next time